# <c:url value="/faq#1" var="faqLink"> How to preserve # in exported variable which is mandatory and wrap functionality into tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm working on application which uses # in URL's for localization purposes.

This means that when I hit `http://host:port/context/faq#1`  in the browser I get the properly localized page.

Inside JSP page, I use relative link like this:

```
<c:url value="/faq#1" var="faqLink">
```

and that generates

```
http://host:port/context/faq
```

Now, I know why `#` and everything after it gets truncated, and I can overcome it locally by using something like:

```
<c:url value="/" var="ctx" />
<c:set value="faq#1" var="relativeUrlWithHash" />
<c:set value="${ctx}${relativeUrlWithHash}" var="faqLink" />
```

and use `faqLink` down the page in various places, but, since this will be used often, and for different links, I was trying to create custom tag call for it, to wrap that functionality i.e.

tag call:

```
<customTag:handleUrlWithHash relativeUrlWithHash="faq#1" exportedVariable="faqLink"/>
```

tag body:

```
<%@ attribute name="relativeUrlWithHash" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="exportedVariable" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:url value="/" var="ctx" />
<c:set var="${exportedVariable}" value="${ctx}${relativeUrlWithHash}" scope="request" />
```

but with no success.

Problem is that I get exception:

```
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions
```

which I don't know how to overcome.

So, any suggestion how to pass variable to tag and get it filled with proper data would be welcome :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply attach the hash value when the URL gets used? Like that:

```
<c:url value="/faq" var="faqLink">  
<a href="${faqLink}#1>faq</a>
```